# How to use libSegFault with ROS node(let)s?

Tags: ros, c++, cmake

I'm trying to debug a segmentation fault on a ROS nodelet. I've tried to use [libSegFault](https://lemire.me/blog/2023/05/01/under-linux-libsegfault-and-addr2line-are-underrated/) by adding the following lines to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES -lSegFault)
```

Further, if I enable verbose output with:

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
```

I can see that the nodelet library is indeed being compiled with `-g` and linked against `libSegFault`.

However, no additional output is generated when the nodelet crashes.

What am I missing? Is the output maybe being suppressed by the ROS logger?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that (as shown [here](https://www.marcusfolkesson.se/blog/libsegfault/)) I had to set the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable prior to starting the nodelet, for example:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSegFault.so roslaunch ...
```

A dump was then correctly printed after the nodelet crashed.